# Ошибка при авторизации пользователя Django 2

Tags: django, авторизация

Недавно начал изучать Django, пытаюсь реализовать авторизацию пользователя на сайте.

В фале forms.py создал форму:

```py
class UserAuthorizationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False, label="Login")
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=False)

    username.widget.attrs.update({"class": "form-control"})
    password.widget.attrs.update({"class": "form-control"})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']

    def __str__(self):
        return format(self.user.username)
```

В фале views.py создал класс:

```py
class Authorization(View):
    reg_templates = 'AuthPage/Registration.html'
    auth_template = 'AuthPage/Authorization.html'
    list_templates = 'AuthPage/AuthPage.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = UserAuthorizationForm
        return render(request, self.auth_template, {"form": form})

    def post(self, request):
        user_form = UserAuthorizationForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            username = user_form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = user_form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(requset, user)
            return render(requset, self.list_templates)
        else:
            raise ValidationError(user_form.errors)
```

И шаблон

```html
{% extends 'AuthPage/base_auth.html' %}
{% block title %}
    Authorization
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post" style="width: 400px" action="{% url 'auth_form_url' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% for user in form %}

            {% if user.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    {{user.errors}}
                </div>
            {% endif %}

            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <lable>{{ user.label }}</lable>
                {{ user }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <div class="form-group form-check">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
        </div>
        <a class="form-group form-check" href="{% url 'reg_form_url'%}">If your dont have account, your want registration</a>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

При отправки формы с логином и паролем зарегистрированного пользователя, на этапе проверки валидациии, django выдёт ошибку:
`{'username': ['A user with that username already exists.']}`
Логично, что при авторизации, пользователь существует. Подскажите пожалуйста, с чем может быть связанно данное поведение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался. Нужно было наследоваться не от `forms.ModelForm`, а от `forms.Form`

Comment: Вообще для авторизашки хороша была бы FormView, где при form_valid вы вызываете login(), get_success_url() - редирект на страницу (ссылка)... и да, проверяете что польдователь есть и его пароль верен в форме в clean(). вроде писать меньше и симпатичнее смотрится.

Comment: Не так давно начал изучать Django, всех тонкостей не знаю. Спасибо за коментарий, учту)